# reading file from s3 (boto3) in multithread fashion

Tags: python, multithreading, amazon-s3, boto3, python-multithreading

I would like to process an huge folder of XML files locate in s3 buckets. I would like to do this in a distributed way in Python.

So I first define a paginator with `boto3` library, setting up (for example) a page size of `100` elements (refer to [doc](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/paginators.html))

```
profile = boto3.Session()
client = profile.client('s3')
paginator = client.get_paginator('list_objects')

page_iterator = paginator.paginate(
    Bucket='my-bucket',Prefix='my-prefix',
    PaginationConfig={'PageSize': 100}
)
```

after that with `concurrent.futures` package I create a pool of `10` threads each of which calling `my_process_method`:

```
def my_process_method(pages):
    for page in pages['Contents']:
        # ...process...

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(10) as executor:
    executor.map(my_process_method, page_iterator)
```

I would like to know if there are some drawbacks in this example, eg. concurrent `boto3` API calls can cause some sort of problems

Answer (score 0):

Does this code work for you. I always just get the first 1000 files of the first page if I do something like

```
global keys
keys = []

def my_process_method(pages):
  for item in page['Contents']:
    keys.append(item.get('Key'))
```